# How to use JSON Web Token (JWT) Grant for docusign

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, docusignapi, jwt

How to use JSON Web Token (JWT) Grant for docusign access token. Please provide full example of code (laravel)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find detailed [PHP code examples](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php) that show both authentication flows, including JWT.
The [JWT authentication code](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/JWTService.php) is using the DocuSign [eSign PHP SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client). Here is a snippet:

```
/**
     * Get JWT auth by RSA key
     */
    private function configureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey() {
        self::$apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath($GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['authorization_server']);
        $privateKey = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/'. $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['private_key_file'], true);
        $response = self::$apiClient->requestJWTUserToken(
            $aud = $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['ds_client_id'],
            $aud = $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['ds_impersonated_user_id'],
            $aud = $privateKey,
            $aud = $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['jwt_scope']
        );
```

To use this code you would need to obtain an integration key, and RSA Keypair (use private key) as well as the GUID of the user you're trying to impersonate.